# Read a CSV and interpolate its data

Tags: python, function, csv, interpolation

I have a code in which I need the solar radiance. To calculate it I use the Planck function, which I have defined as:

```
def planck_W(self, x, t):
    return (2*self.h*self.c**2/x**5) / (np.exp(self.h*self.c / (self.k*x*t)) -1)
```

Where `x` is the wavelength and `t` is the temperature, and the output is the radiance value.

However I want to be able to use also values coming from a `CSV` with different solar spectra, which already provides radiance values for different wavelengths. The sturcture of the `CSV` is Name of the spectrum used, `_xx (wavelength), _yy (radiance)`

```
self.spectra_list= pd.read_csv('solar.csv',converters={'_xx': literal_eval, '_yy':literal_eval)

def planck_W(self):
    self.spectra_list= pd.read_csv('solar.csv',converters={'_xx':literal_eval, '_yy':literal_eval)
    return interp1d(   np.array(self._xx)*1e-9,
                           np.array(self._yy),
                           kind='linear')
```

Later I need to use this curve for a calculation at a wavelength range given by another variable, it starts with:

```
n0 = simpson((planck_W(s.wavelength)...
```

and I get the error:

```
planck_W() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I'm kinda new to programming and don't have much idea what I'm doing, how do I manage to make it take the CSV values?

Comment: planck_W() function being used expects just 1 argument and you're giving 2. You pasted 2 versions of planck_W()  function but none of them is used in your run. I'm guessing you might have many planck_W()  functions around. As long as each of them has different number of arguments it is fine. Also when you pasted a "start" of something and not the cause you're skiping an important part. To make people understand the problem you need to find where exactly the error happens. I mean finding exact line of your code when the error is thrown. If you paste that line instead it will be a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
def planck_W(self):
```

This is the function signature which expects only `self`. But, while calling the function `s.wavelength` is supplied.

This causes the the error `takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`.

Comment: @smoczyna had there been a class defined in the code, `self` would refer to the instance the method is called on but in the context of the provided code `self` is just an argument to the function `planck_W`

Comment: I'm just guessing it has to be, it doesn't look like a full code after all

Answer (score 0):

self is not an argument in your case. Since you not pasted whole code I'm just guessing that planck_W() function is a part of a bigger picture which need to a class indeed.

If this is the case your function call should look like this:

```
n0 = simpson(planck_W())
```

wavelength value you put in your call is not used anywhere.

Otherwise, if you need that value, you have to add wavelength parameter like this:

```
def planck_W(self, wavelength):
```

and then use it inside the function

I hope this explains the situation

Comment: `self` is a keyword only in the scope of a class. There is no class defined in the provided code thus `self` is an argument and is not provided automatically in that code.

Comment: fair enough, wrong wording indeed

Answer (score 0):

You should understand the difference between a `function` and a `method`.

### Function

A function is a piece of code that may or may not take arguments/keywords and perform some actions.

The main reason for a function to be a thing might be to prevent repeating same code.

Example:

Calculate the `sin` of a given angle (In radians) See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine#Series_definition

```
angle = 3.1416

factorial3 = 1
for i in range(1, 4):
    factorial3 *= i

factorial5 = 1
for i in range(1, 6):
    factorial5 *= i

factorial7 = 1
for i in range(1, 8):
    factorial7 *= i

sine = angle - ((angle * angle * angle) / factorial3) + ((angle * angle * angle * angle * angle) / factorial5) - \
       ((angle * angle * angle * angle * angle * angle * angle) / factorial7)
```

We can see the repeating pattern here.

The factorial and power are used multiple times. Those can be functions:

```
def factorial(n):
    result = 1
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        result *= i
    return result

def power(base, pow):
    result = 1
    for _ in range(pow):
        result *= base
    return result

sine2 = angle - (power(angle, 3) / factorial(3)) + (power(angle, 5) / factorial(5)) - (power(angle, 7) / factorial(7))
```

### Method

A method is a function of a class.

We can create an object from a class and ask questions to the object (using method and attributes) and get results.

When you are calling a method of a class you use name spacing as such:

```
object_from_class = TheClass()
object_from_class.the_method(*possible_args)
```

Now you refereeing to `the_method` of the `object_from_class`.

The question is what if you want to refer to a method of the object inside the object.

Let's say we have a class which does trigonometric operations. We can have a `sin`, `cos`, `tan` etc.

You see here when we trying to calculate `tan` we do not need a whole new method. We can use `sin/cos`. Now I need to refer to the methods inside the object.

```
class Trigonometry:
    def sin(self, angle):
        return some_thing
    
    def cos(self, angle):
        return some_thing_else
    
    def tan(self, angle):
        return self.sin(angle) / self.cos(angle)
```

`self.sin` is equivalent of `object_from_class.the_method` when you are inside the object.

Note: Some languages, such as `javascript`, uses`this` instead of `self`

Now, in your case, you are calling a method of an object `def planck_W(self):` which takes no arguments (technically it takes 1 argument but you should provide none) and passing some. That's why python is complaining about what number of arguments.